# Vagrant + Docker - "not ready for rsync"

Tags: vagrant, docker, rsync

I've got an app I'm trying to get vagrant/docker-ized.  Here's the source:  https://github.com/brian-gates/ember-app-kit

After `vagrant up`, `vagrant rsync` gives me the error "The machine is reporting that it is not ready for rsync to communicate with it. Verify that this machine is properly running"

Here's the full log: https://gist.github.com/brian-gates/7018cb65947cd4c22f9c

I'm on Windows 7 if that's relevant.

How can I get it so I can use rsync and rsync-auto?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your docker machine wasn't in running state. Do a 'vagrant status', make sure your 'vagrant up' made the machine running.

If you failed to run the docker machine, there might be misconfiguration in your vagrantfile. Please let me know if you need further help.